# Fetching values from this.props.children

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can we fetch the values  from `this.props.children`. Having logged the output of the same, I am able to see the value of the object but it's nested inside two levels of react classes.

Does React provide any abstracted methods to pick values from this object? Or should I loop them and pick them out one by one?

Use case - I am making a generic table with customizable `<td>` values with custom props. My aim is to check, if some prop exists in `<td>` change behaviour of the table accordingly (scope of this behaviour is to be defined in the `CustomTable` class itself)

This is my custom table -

```
<CustomTable>{this.props.children}</CustomTable>
```

This is how I am calling

```
<CustomTable>
    <thead>....</thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td customPropEnabled={true}> xyz</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</CustomTable>
```

**EDIT**

Just realised, there were two levels of nesting due to the `<table>` structure. One being for type `<tbody>` and one being for type `<tr>`. So, is there any method which can pick the component value out of this object or looping it through is the only way to go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`React.Children.toArray`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildrentoarray) to convert the `children` into an array, and recursively check if there is a `td` with a `customPropEnabled` prop set to true in the nested children.

**Example**

```js
const checkForCustomProp = children => {
  let childArray = React.Children.toArray(children);
  let child;
  let hasCustomProp = false;

  for (let i = 0; i < childArray.length; i++) {
    child = childArray[i];
    if (child.type === "td" && child.props.customPropEnabled) {
      return true;
    } else if (child.props && child.props.children) {
      hasCustomProp = checkForCustomProp(child.props.children);
    }
  }

  return hasCustomProp;
};

function CustomTable(props) {
  const { children } = props;
  const hasCustomProp = checkForCustomProp(children);

  return (
    <div>
      <table>{children}</table>
      {hasCustomProp && <div>Has custom prop!</div>}
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <CustomTable>
    <thead>....</thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td customPropEnabled>xyz</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </CustomTable>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Yes, this should do it. How much is the overhead for such operations? My usual case is around 50-100 rows with 6-7 columns per row. Recursively using it would probably result in multiplied number of operations. Would it still be a resource intensive operation?

Comment: @AseemUpadhyay It's difficult to say without doing measurements for your particular use case. I personally think the extra calculations will be negligible.

Comment: Hmm. I feel that too, if the underlying api's are just plain loops, iterating it around for 300-700 times per table shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @AseemUpadhyay I updated the answer with [React.Children.toArray](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildrentoarray), which might be a bit faster since it uses a simple for loop it can return early from.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [React.Children](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildren) API.

> React.Children provides utilities for dealing with the this.props.children opaque data structure.